# Making permanent changes to a SAS config file

Tags: sas

I'm trying to make a permanent change to my SAS config file (sasv9.cfg). Specifically, I want to increase the MEMSIZE option from -MEMSIZE 2G to -MEMSIZE MAX.

The instructions from SAS on how to do this are on this page under *Overview of Changing SAS System Option Settings' ... http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0drw76qo0gig2n1kcoliekh605k.htm#p0273uv4qrgcrjn16vg7muluuhrz

Using SAS' text editor I am able to access the config file (sasv9.cfg) and make the changes to the appropriate line of code.

The problem is that SAS won't let me *save* those changes, stipulating that the 'administrator' has to approve them. **I am** the administrator but I don't know enough about how SAS' OS works to enable the save.

Any suggestions on workarounds to this issue would be most welcome.

Comment: How are you running SAS?  Is this a "Base SAS" (Display Manager, where you're running sas.exe from Windows) installation?  A server installation?  EG? SAS Studio?  Something else?

Comment: you need to edit the file as an administrator, I'm guessing you are on windows, right click in notepad and select run as an administrator, and then open the file through menu > file > open

Comment: @elios264 Ah, rereading I think you have it right - can you put that as an answer please?

Comment: Side note: -MEMSIZE MAX is a _very bad_ idea, unless you have massive amounts of memory.  Set it to 4GB below your total physical memory.  Otherwise SAS may cause your computer to be quite nonresponsive at times.

Comment: @joe Thanks for all of your comments. My box has 32 gig of RAM, 2 GPU chips and 44 core(s). Given that I'm not too concerned about using 'MAX'

Comment: @DJohnson Then I'd use "28G" or so.  The point is that if SAS does decide to use all 32GB, your system will grind to a halt.

Comment: @joe ok...that sounds like a prudent suggestion.

Comment: You can run the SAS icon 'as Administrator' and then be able to edit and save any file on the system.  You are better off copying the system default config file to your user home and editing that.  Then change your SAS icon properties target to use the -config in your user home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the file as an Administrator since I'm guessing you are on Windows,

Right click in notepad app and select run as an Administrator:

[image]

Then open the file `sasv9.cfg` through menu > file > open

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion enabled me to make and save the changes. The new issue is that, even after rebooting the machine, the CPU and memory utilization hasn't changed. Any ideas or suggestions wrt that? Maybe that's another SO query.

Comment: @DJohnson I don't know much about SAS, but maybe is because it won't use it  (RAM) unless it needs it?